# Prove the limit is $\sqrt{e}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> How do you show
>   $$\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(2+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k}{2^k}=\sqrt{e}$$

I know that $$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=e$$ but I don't know how to apply this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\frac{a^k}{b^k}=\left(\frac ab\right)^k,$$ and in general, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xk\right)^k=e^x.$$

Comment: The latter can be proven by substituting $k=mx$, and least for positive $x$. (The negative case isn't that hard, but it's also not relevant to this problem.)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{\Bigl(2+\dfrac{1}{k}\Bigr)^k}{2^k}=\Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{2k}\Bigr)^k=\sqrt{\Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{2k}\Bigr)^{2k}}.$$